# A word for a person who expects other people to be like him

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a person who expects other people to be like him, for example, a dad who wants his son to be like him?

Comment: Average? Common?

Comment: is there an equivalent in other languages?

Comment: @Sej: I don't get what you are getting at.

Comment: pro-[parthenogenesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis) ? pro-[mitosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitosis) ?  An [archaea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea) ?

Comment: @MrHen: nice rhyme.

Comment: Instead of viewing "man" as the measure of all things, he views himself as being such a measure—hence, _autometronic_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a single word which describes what you're asking for. You probably need a short phrase to give this idea:

> He expects others *to follow his example*.
>
> He wants his son *to take after him*.
>
> He thinks he *knows what's best* for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

A narcissist?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism#Narcissistic_traits):

> -Difficulty with empathy
>   -Problems distinguishing the self from others
>   -Inability to view the world from the perspective of other people

Answer (score 1):

[*Intolerant*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intolerant)?

Comment: Uhm in my opinion it's necessarily negative while in the question's example "if a dad wants his son to be like him" it isn't necessarily negative, right? Unless he forces his son too, but in that case we would have a context. Just a doubt of mine :D

Comment: @Alenanno: the key word for me is "expect", and the rather broad "other people". It's one thing if I would like to see my son become an engineer, but it's a different thing entirely if I "*expect* other people to be like me". But of course, the OP is welcome to clarify.

Comment: Ah I see the subtle difference now. What is an OP by the way?

Comment: @Alenanno: original poster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a word to mean someone who holds people to the highest standards: perfectionist.  I think you can also find a word to mean you want to imitate others:  mimic.

Though I think no one word exists which combines these two ideas perfectly.  I suppose the closest you can get is *perfectionist* or perhaps *idealistic*, for someone who might very well expect others to be like him.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- role model
- model
- icon
- idol
- example
- teacher
- guide
- trailblazer
- leader

The idea of a son being like the father can be expressed as:

- fated
- inherited
- a chip off the old block
- an apple that didn't fall far from the tree
- succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Also consider

- *[zealot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zealot)*, one who is zealous, one who is full of zeal for his own specific beliefs or objectives, [often] too passionate; a fanatic
- *[missionary](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/missionary)*, Someone who attempts to convert others to a particular doctrine or program
- *[evangelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist)*, as used in "technology evangelist", a person who attempts to build a critical mass of support for a given technology
- *[apostle](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/apostle)*, An ardent early supporter of a cause or reform
- *[proselytizer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proselytize)*, someone who encourages or induces people to join a movement, political party, or other cause or organization

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about a person with an unthinking bias, an attitude that is unquestioned and unexamined in themselves. They "expect", meaning: can't conceive otherwise. Given that, I would use the word immature, or naive, depending on whether they have had enough experiences that they ought to have learned better, or haven't yet.

Comment: Welcome to English.se. I am not quite sure why you think *expect* means *can't conceive otherwise* (it does not). For example, *I expect he will arrive at 6* would not mean that I will go insane or be mortified if he arrives at 5 or 7. *Immature* and *naive* both imply not having much experience, so neither seems well suited to a father expecting his child to be similar to himself.

Comment: I read the quotation marks around "expect" to indicate that the poster was expanding not "expect" but something we might call "expect". Assuming "can't conceive otherwise" is appropriate to the situation then "expect" would seem a reasonable shorthand for the OP to use, and reversing this would also be reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

An **autocrat**, maybe—in the sense suggested in the following definition of *autocratic* from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/autocratic):

> Taking no account of other people’s wishes or opinions; domineering: *an autocratic management style*

Comment: You could make your answer stronger by including a relevant dictionary definition of _autocrat_ that indicates its suitability of the word to the questioner's context.

Comment: We appreciate the desire to help, but please consider either expanding your answer or deleting it. Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed. [(more¹)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post) [(more²)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/lots-of-not-always-useful-but-well-intentioned-answers)

Comment: A specific word was requested. I provided a word, with a definition. The definition I gave is copied and pasted nearly verbatim from Merriam-Webster.

Comment: I recommend that you provide a link to the definition you used in your answer, or quote it verbatim and identify the source by exact title. The definitions given at [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autocrat) are as follows: "Simple Definition of **autocrat :** a person who rules with total power[.]  Full Definition of **autocrat 1 :** a person (as a monarch) ruling with unlimited authority **2 :** one who has undisputed influence or power[.]" None of those definitions seems more than tangentially related to the definition you give.

Comment: My mistake - it wasn't Merriam-Webster, but Oxford.http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/autocratic